# Output the ranking number of a players ranking?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm sorting my table which has the `id` and `highscore` of the user. This is ordered in descending and I'm passing in the id of the current user to find where he ranks.

I.e: I pass in the ID of the current user and want to `echo` where he ranks.

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from players
  order by highscore desc
  limit 10
) t
where id = $current_user
```

I've tried this but no luck with getting the data output in PHP..

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank FROM players WHERE highscore >= (SELECT highscore FROM players WHERE id=$current_user)");
```

What must I modify to the above to get that users ranking and then `echo` out his ranking number in PHP? Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with your query? It looks correct.

Comment: I can't seem to get the data of the user's ranking from my second query as above

Comment: What data is being returned from the second query? Are there any errors?

Comment: I do an `echo $mysqli->error;` but get nothing returned. What I'm wondering is how to `echo` the `rank` :)

Comment: If I run the query in phpmyadmin I get the tabled "rank" with the rank number. How do I now echo that out in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the data into an array once you query it from the database. Try using [mysqli's `fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank FROM players WHERE highscore >= (SELECT highscore FROM players WHERE id=$current_user)");

// Put the data from the query into an array
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

// Store the rank in a variable named $rank
$rank = $row['rank'];

echo $rank;
```